# High Availability for WSO2 ELB

Tags: wso2

I am following the link "http://docs.wso2.org/display/ELB201/Setup+ELB+with+WSO2+Application+Server" to setting cluster for AS.

But I have a problem.

There is only one ELB in this scenario. If there is something wrong with this ELB, all the worker nodes will never work.

Does anyone know how to set more than one ELB in a cluster.when one ELB does not work, other ELBs will still work for all the work nodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do that. [This](http://docs.wso2.org/display/ELB210/Automatic+Failover) (1) will explain you how to setup active/passive ELB's with HA which will solve your problem. In this setup failure of one ELB will not affect the serving of requests because the second ELB will send the requests correctly to the desired services.

(1) http://docs.wso2.org/display/ELB210/Automatic+Failover

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can run the ELB in a cluster. Please follow this link to get detailed steps, http://docs.wso2.org/display/ELB210/Using+Load+Balancer+in+a+Cluster

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the latest article on "How to Make WSO2 Elastic Load Balancer highly available through AWS Elastic Load Balancer".

http://wso2.com/library/tutorials/2013/09/make-wso2-elb-highly-available-through-aws-elb/